# Why is parsing a jSON response to a jQUERY ajax request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I know there are several similar questions on SO, I have used some of them to get this far. I am trying to list a set of urls that match my input values. I have a servlet which takes some input e.g. "aus" in the example below and returns some output using out.print() e.g. the two urls I have shown below.

EXAMPLE

- Input: "aus"
- Output: [{"url":"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stifel_Nicolaus"},{"url":"http://sempedia.org/ontology/object/Australia"}]

Which is exactly what I want. I have seen that firebug doesn't seem to have anything in the response section despite having called `out.print(jsonString);` and it seems that `out.print(jsonString);` is working as expected which suggests that the variable 'jsonString' contains the expected values.

However I am not exactly sure what is wrong.

-------- The jQuery  ---------

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input").keyup(function() {
        var input = $("#input").val();
        //$("#output").html(input);
        ajaxCall(input);
    });
});

function ajaxCall(input) {
//  alert(input);
    $.ajax({
        url: "InstantSearchServlet",
        data: "property="+input,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
              if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
               x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
              }
             },
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data) {
                 for (var i = 0, len = datalength; i < len; ++i) {
                     var urlData = data[i];
                     $("#output").html(urlData.url);
                     }                  
            }
          });
        }
```

------ The Servlet that calls the DAO class - and returns the results -------

```
public class InstantSearchServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

 System.out.println("You called?");
    response.setContentType("application/json");        
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    InstantSearch is = new InstantSearch();

    String input = (String)request.getParameter("property");
 System.out.println(input);

    try {
        ArrayList<String> urllist;

        urllist = is.getUrls(input);
        String jsonString = convertToJSON(urllist);
        out.print(jsonString);
  System.out.println(jsonString);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private String convertToJSON(ArrayList<String> urllist) {

    Iterator<String> itr = urllist.iterator();
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
           i++;
           JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
           String url = itr.next();
           try {
            json.put("url",url);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           jArray.put(json);
        }

    String results = jArray.toString();
    return results;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must missed a period, here:

```
for (var i = 0, len = datalength; i < len; ++i) {
```

should be:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `success` handler is trying to reference a variable, `datalength`, that doesn't exist. You probably meant `data.length`.
2. <s>In that same function, you're not declaring `len` anywhere, thus falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).</s> *Yes, you **are** declaring it, I missed the comma. Thanks, Nick.*
3. `application/j-son` isn't the JSON MIME type. It's `application/json`. But that's okay, there's no need to override it in any case. You're sending the correct content type from the server, and you're also telling jQuery to treat it as JSON regardless of what the server says.
4. You're *replacing* the content of your `output` element on each iteration of the loop; did you mean [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) rather than `html`?

Comment: 1,2,3 are all correct thanks. The main thing was datalength being used rather than data.length

Comment: He *is* declaring `len`, it's in the `var` statement of the `for` loop.

Comment: J. - welcome, +1 on the other points, all valid issues for later